# Setting domain in cookie in spark java

Tags: spark-java

Is there a way to set the domain on cookies in spark java? javax.servlet.http.Cookie has a setDomain method but none of the cookie overloads in Spark.Response offers a way to pass the domain and the wrapped HttpServletResponse is private so can't call addCookie on it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 2.9.2 has an overload of the [`Response#cookie()`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.sparkjava/spark-core/2.9.2/spark/Response.html#cookie-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-boolean-boolean-) method that allows you to set the domain.